# How to find continuous zero in a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, loops, sql-server-2008

How do I find continuous zero number(0) in a column and stop when I find a non-zero. Then I need to replace the all the zeroes with the non-zero number.

1. The grouping will be done by column 1
2. After we get a non zero value, for eg - ABC, replace all the values above it with that non zero value.
3. The arrangement in a group will be done by descending order of date.

Please tell me how to update the zero values with the non-zero number. [image]

Comment: Can you update your question with a larger data set, that shows more zeroes and non-zeroes?  Also, I think you will need to tell us a column which can be used for ordering, without which there are no sequences of zeroes well defined.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please check now.

Comment: how come 3rd row of column 2 is 0 for ABC in second data set, it should be 3 as per your requirement

Comment: @Rams - It won't be 3. If we arrange by descending order of DATES for ABC, only the dates after 01-01-2016 will be updated(in ABC). the other two dates for ABC are of 2014 and 2013, hence they will not be updated. In short, only the dates after a non-zero value will be updated for ABC.

Comment: ok, will it be only 1 non-zero value for set of column1??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    Col1 VARCHAR(5),
    Col2 INT,
    Col3 DATE
)

INSERT INTO @T
values( 'ABC',0,'01-01-2017'),('ABC',0,'01-01-2017'),('ABC',0,'01-01-2014'),('ABC',3,'01-01-2013'),
('DEF',0,'01-01-2017'),('DEF',2,'01-01-2017'),('DEF',0,'01-01-2014')

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2,Col3),
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2 DESC),
    *
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    T1.Col1,
    NewCol2 = ISNULL(T2.Col2,T1.Col2),
    OldCol2 = T1.Col2,
    T1.Col3 
    FROM CTE T1
        LEFT JOIN CTE T2
            ON T1.Col1 = t2.Col1
                AND T1.Col2 = 0
                AND T2.RN =1
```

This is the output

[image]

Program Logic :

- It Creates a sequence for each Col1 based on the Col2 and col3.
- For every record with Col2 as 0, it does a lookup on the same table for records having same value in col1 and Rank = 1 ( Rank 1 will be the record with values <> 0 )
- if a match is found based on the above, matching value is displayed else the value is displayed as in the column

Comment: Nice one. But the last row should not be updated as 2 is before it and not after.

Comment: How you define the last one ? Based on the dates ?

Comment: Yes. Based on the dates.

Comment: Hi, could you please explain me the solution?

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain what is T1 and T2?

Comment: those are just alias names, you can use any as you wish

Answer (score 2):

You can try this solution, but you will also need an `id`column (auto-increment i recommend):

```
declare @tbl as table (
    id int
    ,column1 varchar(5)
    ,column2 int
)

insert into @tbl values (1, 'ABC', 0)
insert into @tbl values (2, 'DEF', 0)
insert into @tbl values (3, 'GHI', 0)
insert into @tbl values (4, 'JKL', 3)
insert into @tbl values (5, 'GHI', 0)
insert into @tbl values (6, 'JKL', 0)
insert into @tbl values (7, 'JKL', 4)

SELECT
    id
    ,column1
    ,CASE WHEN
        column2 = 0 THEN
            (SELECT TOP 1 column2 
            FROM @tbl <-- here you query the table again
            WHERE id > T.id <-- based on this condition you are looking onto the next row (as explained below)
                AND column2 <> 0
            ORDER BY id)
        ELSE column2
    END AS column2
FROM @tbl T <-- Here is T; is the alias of the table
```

**UPDATE**

---

If your `column2 = 0` the subquery looks into your table and takes the first non-zero value it finds.

I was telling you about the `id` column cause you need a sub-query from the same table, with this condition `WHERE id > T.id` the query looks on the next row, if it has a non-zero value will return it, otherwise will look at the next row and so on ...

So for example when `id = 1` the subquery search in your table search for an `id > 1` to take the first non-zero value it finds; in this case the subquery will find the record with `id = 4` and returns the value 3 and the `CASE` statement will do the rest.

Comment: Can you please explain the following code : WHERE id > T.id ? What is T.id ?

Answer (score 0):

could you please check following SQL statement
Unfortunately, to find the next or previous rows in a table, we have to use a field to "ORDER BY"
Although you see rows are ordered as inserted, this is not guaranteed. It is safe to take a column like identity, or datetime column for sorting and referencing your rows which is next or previous

```
; with cte as (
select 
    z.*, s.id sid, s.Column2 sColumn2, 
    row_number() over (partition by z.id order by s.id) as rn
from zeros as z, zeros as s
where
    z.id < s.id and
    z.Column2 = 0 and
    s.Column2 > 0
)
update z
set
    Column2 = upd.sColumn2
from zeros as z
inner join (
select
    id, sColumn2 
from cte
where rn = 1
) upd
on z.id = upd.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If every type of Column1 having only one non-zero value then below solution works fine.

```
    SELECT t1.column1,coalesce(t2.column2,t1.column2) as column2,t1.column3 FROM TABLE t1 
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT column1,column2,column3 FROM TABLE WHERE column2<>0) AS t2 
        ON t1.column1=t2.column1 and t1.column3>=t2.column3
        ORDER BY  t1.column1,t1.column3 DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add column like autoincremented 'idx' or time to order data.

and then

```
update table set Column2=3 where idx > (select idx from table where Column2!=0 limit 0,1)
```

Comment: It's not a good practice to add a new column, just because you need to view data like this.